# .htaccess rewrite URL in PHP usng apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

In my website, I have 3 kind of urls as shown below,

```
index.php?p=my-page
index.php?p=my-page&id=12
index.php?p=my-page&id=12&type=d
```

So, then I need to covert them into

```
example.com/my-page
example.com/my-page/12
example.com/my-page/12/d
```

This is how I tried it in my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # (1)
    RewriteEngine On

    # (2)
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options -MultiViews

    # (3)
    # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

    # (4)
    RewriteBase /

    # (5)
    # RewriteOptions <options>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC,B]
    # RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC,B]
    # RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Above first `RewriteRule` is working for `example.com/my-page`. But second or third is not working for my other 2 urls.

My `<a>` tag is looks this:

```
<a href="/my-page">Page</a> // this is working for me using above first rule
<a href="/my-page/12/">Page</a>
<a href="/my-page/12/d">Page</a>
```

Can anyone tell me why my rule 2 or 3 does not work in this regard?

Comment: What does "is not working" actually mean? Try to be precise. What happens if you make such a request (after removing the comment marks of the 3rd rule, obviously)? Do you get an error in your http server's error log file? Is the result something unexpected? Does anything happen at all?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [`L` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) on your rules, so once your rule matches, Apache restarts its checks for matches on the substitution. You're also missing the [`DPI` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_dpi), so that substitution is not just `index.php?...` because the `PATH_INFO` is appended. What people typically want instead of `L` is [`END`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end).

You could also condense them into a single rule so you don't have to repeat the `RewriteCond` directives for each one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]++)(?:/([1-9]\d*+)(?:/([^/]++))?+)?+/?+$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&type=$3 [END,QSA,NC,B]
```

See the unit tests section of [the regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hcy9I9/3).

In your PHP, ensure parameters are not the empty string, e.g.:

```php
$id = $_GET['id'] ?? '';
if ($id !== '') {
    ...
}
```